# Insert data from the clipboard into the attribute table's column (Do not create new features)

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, paste

Is it possible to insert data from the clipboard into the column? (Do not create new points)
I have a table where I need to change the data of one attribute. I have the new data for the attribute in an excel table, sorted to match the rows of the displayed attribute table. If I try to insert the data (CTRL-V) new points are created (without coordinates).

How do I get it to just copy the data from the clipboard to the selected column to the existing points?

Comment: Are you trying to paste data to a whole (existing) column or the intended copy-paste procedure affects only some cells?

Comment: I try add data to whole (existing) column. All features (rows)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that both the layer and the excel share an `id` and the `field` you want to update, what I would do is:

1. Import the excel file as a layer;
2. Make the original layer editable;
3. Use the field calculator to update the `field` with the following expression `attribute(get_feature('excel_layer', 'id', "id"), 'field')`